# How do I open a Rails Mysql database in Mysql Workbench?

Tags: mysql, database, ruby-on-rails, mysql-workbench

I having **trouble finding my mysql database files** in Ruby on Rails project and **opening it in MysqlWorkbench**

This is my folder structure for a app

[image]

This is my **database.yml**

```
development:

  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: rawdy_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I'm not finding my mysql database file to open in MySqlWorkbench.
Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `sqlite`, your rails project doesn't contain the MySQL database files, the `database.yml` file only contains info on how to connect to the database. In that case it's trying to connect through a unix socket file.

I'm  not sure if Workbench can connect that way, but most likely the database server is located on your own machine at `localhost`, port `3306`, using username `root` and a blank password, you should configure Workbench to connect to that server and use database `rawdy_development`, instead of opening a database file.

Comment: does that means the files behavior depends on which database we choose?